# APNS: Sending the same notification more than once

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app to which I can send push notifications. When a user saves something in the app, the time of saving is put in a mysql-database on my server in the table "active_users". My server runs a script to see if the time has ran out and if it has, it sends a notification to the device.

See the strange thing here is that during the very first test of the system, the push notification reached my phone and everything went well. I did some changes and tried again, but now nothing seems to happen.

What is really strange here is that I have a push_queue (a table in my DB) in which messages to push (token and payload) are put when it is time for them to be pushed. When I run my test, the message is added to the push_queue and in my log-file everything is logged as if it went fine.

My question is now: Can I only send one push notification per device token? This is kinda the only solution I can come up with.

This is a paste from my log-file: http://pastebin.com/whkpV3F6
As you can see, it is the same device token used in both message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution myself. This is my situation and solution:

I run my webserver from a Synology Diskstation (DS211+). To be able to run open an SSL-connection via PHP, openssl must be enabled. Do the following to enable PHP on you Synology Diskstation:

1) Open the terminal on your mac)
2) Create an SSH-connection and connect as root (user your "admin"-password)
3) cd /usr/syno/etc.defaults/
4) vi php.ini

Now search for a string in vi using /string: /openssl.dll
This line starts with a semicolon (;) which means that it is commented out. Uncomment the line "extension=php_openssl.dll".

Now restart the apache server using the following command:
/usr/syno/etc.defaults/rc.d/S97apache-user.sh restart

It should now work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The token should be good for any number of messages you want to push to the device, unless the app has been deleted from the device or the app has received a new token from Apple's servers.

1. If the app is deleted, behind the scenes on the device Apple is notified and the token becomes invalidated. You must poll Apple "occasionally" for this feedback, telling you which tokens you should no longer send messages to. You MUST poll the feedback service, or Apple will invalidate your ability to send push notifications.
2. You app needs to request push notification services from Apple on each launch. The token you get back each time may likely never change, but it could. You then need to make sure your server has the correct token.

That all being said, it is unlikely that in your token changed, in this case, since you're just testing.

What is more likely, perhaps, is that the message was just not delivered... I don't believe push notifications are guaranteed to be delivered, much like SMS reliability. I do not think that Apple prevents you from sending the same message more than once, either, but I could be wrong about that; perhaps there *is* some limiter in that regard if duplicate messages are sent in rapid succession. Not sure about that one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First of all, how frequent is "occasionally"? I started developing this morning so could I already be blocked because I ain't polling the feedback service yet (I am not entirely done with it yet). Also, everytime the user saves on his phone, the current token is sent to the server - this means that everytime I test I have the newest token registered.

Comment: Oh, I think occasionally means at some regular interval -- hourly, daily, maybe weekly? I don't think the docs suggest a recommended interval. But the "checking" that Apple does to make sure you are polling the feedback service is surely not at very short intervals. So I wouldn't be worried about that. I think after you deploy your app, you'll want to make sure your feedback polling is up and running at _some_ interval. Glad to hear you're already capturing the up-to-date token.

Comment: I am in the middle of adding APNs to an app; we're using a Ruby GEM to handle the heavy lifting of APNs and it "just works". If you're implementing that heavy lifting yourself, you might look there for issues. Otherwise, I'd look at your server code, despite its logging successful transmission, perhaps something has gone awry there.

Comment: I would appreciate if you'd take a look. I am on my tablet right now so I will paste you the code. Tomorrow. Basically I am modifying the code from Ray Wenderlich's tutorial and yes I am doing it by myself, so feedback from another person might be the solution.

Comment: I might have found the reason. For testing I have used my iMac's terminal but I have moved the system onto my webserver on which it seems that I haven't enabled SSL. I reckon that this might be the reason, but I need to test it before I can make it an answer of the question.

Comment: Thank your for your thoughts MarkGranoff. As you can read I figured it out myself.